# get the deleted attribute back to the live site

Tags: mysql, database, magento

we missly deleted the attribute : "age" from live site.

attribute code : "age" attribute label : Age group

we assigned this  attribute to thousands of products.

is there any option to get that attribute back in database?

we have a yesterday database backup.

is i have to export the **eav_attribute** table from yesterday database and import to the current database?....

for this to do, **is i have to delete the eav_attribute table from current database?**

or is there any option to export and import only particular attribute instead of "eav_attribute" table

Comment: you can import only age column if you wish, you need to know what's the primary Key of your table. then use SQL update syntax with primary key filter. Sorry, did you delete the field or only the field's value?

Comment: i am following this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95868/get-the-deleted-attribute-back-to-the-live-site but i am getting "#1054 - Unknown column 'age' in 'field list' "

Comment: i ran this command : INSERT INTO eav_attribute (age) VALUES (1020);

Comment: the error showed up because, you don't have "age" column in eav_attribute, you have to add the column first

Comment: please help me how i can add it ?

Comment: ALTER TABLE eav_attribute ADD age INTEGER

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99761/discussion-between-webster-and-baby-in-coding).

Comment: @Webster post your comment as answer

Comment: which one that solved your problem dude?

Comment: as you said to import the database attribute from one db to another, you can post  this.....

Comment: okay, i've posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in chat, the attribute/value "age" in your primary table is gone.
You need to import it from your backup table.
Assumed that your backup table is in the same database as your primary table, here's the query

```
INSERT INTO eav_attribute (your columns)
SELECT (your columns)
FROM eav_attribute_backup
WHERE attribute_id = 1092
```

Comment: sure, if you need any help again, just email me tho i've been busy lately :(